# Isomorphism of linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Suppose we have an equation of  linear transformation  $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$.
How to show that such transformation is isomorphic and how to find inverse isomorphism ($\varphi^{-1}$)?

EDIT: The transformation is:
$\varphi ([x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4])=[x_1+x_2+x_3, x_1+x_3+x_4,x_1+x_4,x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4]$

Comment: In general, check that it's a bijective homomorphsim. Whatever this amounts to depends on each case, so maybe you could post an example that you need help with?

Comment: Saying that $\varphi$ is a "linear transformation" or "map" suggests that you are thinking of it as a map that preserves vector space operations.  In that context you already have the map preserving the operations of a vector space, so as GPerez tells you, what remains is checking whether the map is 1-1 and onto (injective and surjective) for the indicated domain and codomain.

Comment: I've just added the precise linear map equation i am talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix of the linear map with respect to the standard basis is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and Gaussian elimination goes as follows
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\[1ex]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\[1ex]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\[1ex]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
which shows the rank of the matrix is $4$. So the map is surjective, hence also injective.

In order to find the inverse, a good method is to proceed with finding the RREF of the matrix $[A\ I_4]$:
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|cccc@{}}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|cccc@{}}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\\[1ex]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|cccc@{}}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\\[1ex]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|cccc@{}}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\\[1ex]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|cccc@{}}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\\[1ex]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|cccc@{}}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\\[1ex]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cccc|cccc@{}}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\end{align}
which shows that
$$
A^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that
$$
\varphi^{-1}([x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4])=
[x_1-x_4,-x_2+x_3,x_1-x_3,-x_1+x_2+x_4]
$$

Comment: Probably this question is because of my insufficient knowledge but fact that map is surjective and injective implies isomorphism?

Comment: @kurkowski Yes: isomorphism means “both injective and surjective”.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the definition of a linear isomorphism of vector spaces. In this case is sufficient for $\dim(\ker(\varphi)) = 0$ and $\dim(\mathrm{im}(\varphi)) = 4$. To help you further requires knowledge of $\varphi$.

EDIT

Ok now try to show that

**(a)** if $\varphi(\mathbb{x}) = 0$ then necessarily $\mathbb{x} = 0$. This shows $\dim(\ker(\varphi)) = 0$, thus injectivity.

**(b)** there are four vectors whose images are linearly independent. This shows that $\dim(\mathrm{im}(\varphi)) = 4$, or surjectivity.

I suggest that trying to find a matrix representation of $\varphi$ would be a very good idea for showing both these points.

For $\varphi^{-1}$, once you have a matrix you can compute its inverse.

Comment: I've just added the precise equation i am talking about

Answer (score 0):

$\phi : \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^4$ is given by $\phi ((x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4))=(x_1+x_2+x_3, x_1+x_3+x_4,x_1+x_4,x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4).$ Let $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^4.$ Then $\phi (e_1)= (1, 1, 1, 1), \phi (e_2) = (1, 0, 0, 1), \phi(e_3)= (1, 1, 0,1), \phi(e_4) = (0, 1, 1, 1).$ Now you need to show that $\{\phi(e_1), \phi(e_2), \phi(e_3), \phi(e_4) \}$ forms a basis of $\mathbb R^4.$

Using Rank-Nullity theorem, to show that a given linear transformation is an isomorphism it is sufficient to check that it maps a basis to a basis.